# Swift: Unable to update a Firebase DB Value

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to update the value of an entry in my Firebase DB from false to true when I press a button. I can get the value of the current snapshot with the following code:

```
@IBAction func test(_ sender: Any) {

ref.child("Sell_Request").queryOrdered(byChild: "name").queryEqual(toValue: requestUsername).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot : FIRDataSnapshot) in

    print(snapshot)

    })
}
```

I am trying to use the following code to update the value of "Request_Made" from false to true, but am getting a SIGBRT.

```
@IBAction func test(_ sender: Any) {


        ref.child("Sell_Request").queryOrdered(byChild: "name").queryEqual(toValue: requestUsername).setValue(true, forKey: "Request_Made");

    }
```

Here is how my DB entry looks in FireBase:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be the correct way to do that.

```
ref.child("Sell_Request").queryOrdered(byChild: "name").queryEqual(toValue: requestUsername).observeSingleEvent(.value, with: { dataSnapshot in
    let enumerator = dataSnapshot.children
    while let sell_request = enumerator.nextObject() as? FIRDataSnapshot {
        sell_request.ref.child("Request_Made").setValue(true)
    }
})
```

Comment: No need to rebuild the reference from the root. You could just use `sell_request.ref.child("Request_Made").setValue(false)`

Comment: You guys are awesome! Thanks to both of you!!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you still need to observe the query.

```
@IBAction func test(_ sender: Any) {

    ref.child("Sell_Request").queryOrdered(byChild: "name").queryEqual(toValue: requestUsername).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in 

       for child in snapshot.children {           

           if let item = child as? FIRDataSnapshot {

               item.ref.setValue(true, forKey: "Request_Made");
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: I wish I could give you both best answers, since both work. Thank you!

Comment: Not a problem. Glad it worked for you. In the future, if both methods work equally well, the question that was posted first is normally the one to be selected as the answer. Happy coding!